# How to web service and parse the xml in button action?

Tags: objective-c, xml, web-services, ios5, uinavigationcontroller

I am finding it difficult to navigate from one page to another page when a web service call is processing. Here is my issue,

I am able to call the web service successfully and get the xml, also I am able to parse the xml and get my required tags. My issue is I am doing all this process in an button action. I want to navigate the page once the web service & parsing is completed. But I couldn't do it since my page is navigating before the service call & parsing is completed.

Below is the code in what I am doing

```
- (IBAction)CIS_Login:(id)sender
{

WebServiceAuth *service = [[WebServiceAuth alloc]init];
NSString *username,*password;

username = CIS_Username.text;
password = CIS_Password.text;
[service getUsername:username getPassword:password]; (Calling Web service)

NSString *getSessionToken = [USERDEFAULTS objectForKey:@"sessionToken"];

if (getSessionToken)
{
    [self receivedSessionTokenFromCloud];
}
else
{
    [self receivedErrorMessageFromCloud];
}
}
```

Web Service Page

```
-(void)getUsername:(NSString *)usernameAuth getPassword:(NSString *)passwordAuth
{
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
                         "<session xmlns=\"http://schemas.XYZ.com/ABC/2011\">"
                         "<account>\n"
                         "<username>%@</username>\n"
                         "<password>%@</password>\n"
                         "</account>\n"
                         "</session>",usernameAuth,passwordAuth];

NSLog(@"%@",soapMessage);


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://XYZ.com/sessions"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];

[theRequest addValue:@"Token" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Code"];
[theRequest addValue:@"application/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest addValue: @"application/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSLog(@"%@",[theRequest allHTTPHeaderFields]);

NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
if(theConnection)
{
    Data = [NSMutableData data];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
}
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [Data length]);
NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [Data mutableBytes] length:[CiscoData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",theXML);
UserOAuthXML *xmlOAuth = [[UserOAuthXML alloc]init]; (Xml Parsing is done here)
[xmlOAuth getDataFromUserOAuth:Data];
}
```

Xml Parser page

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"code"])
{
    recordResult = FALSE;
    NSLog(@"%@",soapResults);
    [USERDEFAULTS setValue:soapResults forKey:@"code"];
}
else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"message"])
{
    recordResult = FALSE;
    NSLog(@"%@",soapError);
    [USERDEFAULTS removeObjectForKey:@"value"];

}
}
```

Please I hope you understand my query. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
- (IBAction)CIS_Login:(id)sender
{
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(Action:) withObject:sender waitUntilDone:YES];   
}




-(void) Action{
WebServiceAuth *service = [[WebServiceAuth alloc]init];
NSString *username,*password;

username = CIS_Username.text;
password = CIS_Password.text;
[service getUsername:username getPassword:password]; (Calling Web service)

NSString *getSessionToken = [USERDEFAULTS objectForKey:@"sessionToken"];

if (getSessionToken)
{
    [self receivedSessionTokenFromCloud];
}
else
{
    [self receivedErrorMessageFromCloud];
}
}
```

hope it helps.. happy coding :)

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, but still the page is navigating before the call is completed

Comment: can u add the code where u r pushing the UIViewController object.

Comment: `-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [Data length]);
NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [Data mutableBytes] length:[CiscoData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",theXML);
UserOAuthXML *xmlOAuth = [[UserOAuthXML alloc]init]; (Xml Parsing is done here)
[xmlOAuth getDataFromUserOAuth:Data];
}
`

Comment: this method is for web interaction, i need code for the pushViewController of the UIViewController that u r pushing once the data is fetched

Comment: `-(void)receivedSessionTokenFromCloud
{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        URLConfig *Config = [[URLConfig alloc]initWithNibName:@"URLConfig_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:Config animated:YES];
    } 
    else
    {
        URLConfig *Config = [[URLConfig alloc]initWithNibName:@"URLConfig" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:Config animated:YES];
    }
}`

Comment: try [service performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(getUsername:getPassword:) withObject:username,password waitUntilDone:YES]; instead of [service getUsername:username getPassword:password];

Comment: how can we send 2 objects in "withObject:username,password" it will only accept 1 value. Can you clarify this.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)send_report
{

NSLog(@"self.get_hardstring-------------===:%@",self.get_hardstring);
NSLog(@"self.get_softstring-------------===:%@",self.get_softstring);


NSString *sopMessage=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
                      "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
                      "<soap:Body>"
                      "<BreakDown xmlns=\"http://swag.test.com/swag/\">"
                       "<hardstring>%@</hardstring>"
                      " <softstring>%@</softstring>"
                      "</BreakDown>"
                      "</soap:Body>"
                      "</soap:Envelope>",self.get_hardstring,self.get_softstring];

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://swag.test.com/webservice.asmx"];//
NSMutableURLRequest *req=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msglength=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[sopMessage length]];
[req addValue:@"text/xml;charset=utf-8"  forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[req addValue:@"http://swag.test.com/swag/BreakDown" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"]; //



[req addValue: msglength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[req setHTTPBody:[sopMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];



if (conn) 
{
    webData = [[NSMutableData data]retain];

}




NSError *error1;

error1 = [[[NSError alloc] init] autorelease];

NSData *returnData1 = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:nil error:&error1];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"returnString===:%@",returnString);

NSRange match;
NSRange match1;

match = [returnString rangeOfString: @"<BreakDownResult>"];

//NSLog (@"match found at index %i", match.location);   [soapResults setString:@""];

match1 = [returnString rangeOfString: @"</BreakDownResult>"];

//NSLog (@"match found at index %i", match1.location);  [soapResults setString:@""];    

//
//NSString *str=match.location
int t1= match.location+match.length;
int t2=match1.location-t1;


NSString *string2;

string2 = [returnString substringWithRange: NSMakeRange (t1, t2)];


if ([string2 isEqualToString:@"inserted SuccessFully!"])
{
    UIAlertView *alrt1 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:@"Statement Successfully Send" delegate:self
                                         cancelButtonTitle:nil 
                                         otherButtonTitles:@"Ok",nil];
    [alrt1 show];
    [alrt1 release];


}
else 
{
    UIAlertView *alrt1 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:@"Statement Not Send" delegate:self
                                         cancelButtonTitle:nil 
                                         otherButtonTitles:@"Ok",nil];
    [alrt1 show];
    [alrt1 release];    
}

}
```